# how to get video frame (bitmap) of video file from raw folder

Tags: android, bitmap, android-videoview

I am working on application, where i am using **video's stored in raw folder**.

In this case I **want to show frame or bitmap to my videoview**.

I have used this,

```
Uri  videoURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"
            +R.raw.cashword_video);
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(this, videoURI);
    Bitmap bitmap = retriever
          .getFrameAtTime(100000,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367019/how-to-get-video-thumb-nail-from-raw-folder-video-on-android)
where many people says that video's should be stored on sd card, but my requirement is of raw folder.
Here one guy is also saying that code is working for him but in my case it's not working.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly how it is not working? Is there an exception?

Comment: There is no any exception or error but i am not getting any bitmap or image there.

Comment: it is returning me blank image, it is not returning proper frame of video. I tried changing time but it won't worked.

Comment: It worked for me too. You have add one more line at the end:
`imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);`