# Not getting realpath of video from /res/raw android

Tags: android, video

I want to show thumbnail before playing video.My video is in /res/raw folder.I am trying following method to get Real path of my video file.But `getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj , null, null, null)` this returning null without any exception.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {      
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj , null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Am I missing something? Any permission in Manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying following method to get Real path of my video file.

There is no "real path" to your video, because it is not a file. It is an entry in the APK.

> I want to show thumbnail before playing video

Since the video is a resource, prepare your own thumbnail on your development machine and package that as a resource as well.

Comment: Uri  videoURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/" +R.raw.grilled_daily_sandwich);
     MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
     retriever.setDataSource(this, videoURI);
     Bitmap bitmap = retriever
           .getFrameAtTime(200000,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
     BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
  videoView.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
not workoing always.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367019/how-to-get-video-thumb-nail-from-raw-folder-video-on-android